# How to get attributes from JSON object returned by ajax request PHP?

Tags: jquery, json

I can't figure out how I'd select variables in this JSON object..

When I try to do like alert(data.vnaam) it returns `undefined`...

```
{vnaam: "Henk", tv: "", anaam: "Jansen", adres: "Meeuwweg 12", postcode: "8765 AP"}
```

This is my AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
    url :   "action.php",
    method: "GET",
    data    :   ({pers:id}),
    success :   function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
});
```

Comment: You need to parse the json object

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the JSON object:

```
$.ajax({
    url :   "action.php",
    method: "GET",
    data    :   {pers:id},
    success :   function(data){
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        alert(obj.vnaam);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse response

convert this

```
alert(data);
```

to this

```
var json=JSON.parse(data);
alert(json.vnaam)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `dataType: json` :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "action.php",
    method: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {   
        //Your code
    }
});
```

Or you could also use the jQuery method `$.getJson()` that will load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request :

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
     $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
         console.log( key, val );
     });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is that not what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

If your object is formatted correctly, then you can just access the properties as they are...:

```
var data = {
  vnaam: "Henk", 
  tv: "", 
  anaam: "Jansen", 
  adres: "Meeuwweg 12", 
  postcode: "8765 AP"
};

console.log(data.vnaam);
```

Here's a fiddle to show you it working: https://jsfiddle.net/nw44j9ev/